# Setting up height of label constraint in collectionview cell programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to setup height constraint for a label in `collectionview cell`

```
   class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
   override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
      constraint()
    }
   func constraint() {

        label.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:label, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 25))
    }
}
```

I did the above and it is not working. Does the `layoutSubviews` declaration work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a convenience way to use constraint and change it in code.

**First,** declare a constraint property:

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

**Second,** bind it in XIB or Stroyboard:
[image]

**Finally,** you are able to change it in programming way:

```
self.labelHeight.constant = 130
```

Comment: I am using collectionview and I cannot do it because it says "Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content"

Comment: @leaner122, the label is in a CollectionViewCell, so the binding should be between a property of CollectionviewCell CLASS and a Label constraint of CollectionviewCell in a XIB or Stroryborad.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: label, attribute:.Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant:25.0)
```

or

```
NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(@"V:[label(==24)]", options: nil , metrics: nil, views: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label))
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

> (...)you must specify a value for each parameter, even if it doesn’t affect the layout. The end result is a considerable amount of boilerplate code, which is usually harder to read. (...)